# How to check if private/public key pair match using (.NET / BouncyCastle)?

Tags: c#, .net, cryptography, bouncycastle

I have AsymmetricKeyParameter object for private and public key. What is the easiest way to see if they match?

I am trying to encrypt some text (private key) and decrypt some text (public key). 
So far I have not been able to do that but it seems like the wrong approach.

Update: Here is sample code:

```
X509Certificate2 c = new X509Certificate2(@"certificate.cer");
byte[] privateKeyData = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(@"private.key");
Org.BouncyCastle.X509.X509Certificate cert = DotNetUtilities.FromX509Certificate(c);


RsaPrivateCrtKeyParameters privateKey = (RsaPrivateCrtKeyParameters)PrivateKeyFactory.CreateKey(privateKeyData);
RsaKeyParameters publicKey = (RsaKeyParameters)cert.GetPublicKey();

if (privateKey.Modulus.Equals(publicKey.Modulus) && publicKey.Exponent.Equals(privateKey.PublicExponent)) 
{
     //they match
}
```

Comment: If you are decrypting with public key, are you actually attempting to sign the data rather than encrypt?

Comment: I want to match the keys, I just do not know how to go about doing it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The simplest way to check whether a private key and a public key match is to encrypt a piece of data with the public key and see if you can decrypt it with the private key - or alternatively to sign a piece of data with the private key and see if you can verify it with the public key.

If the keys are RSA keys, you can cast the public key to `Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.Parameters.RsaKeyParameters` and the private key to `Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.Parameters.RsaPrivateCrtKeyParameters` and verify that the `Modulus` is the same and that `Exponent` of the public key is equal to `PublicExponent` of the private key. If you want to get really fancy, you could also validate all the remaining parameters of the private key (follow [PKCS#1](ftp://ftp.rsasecurity.com/pub/pkcs/pkcs-1/pkcs-1v2-1.pdf) section 3.2).

Comment: Thank you for the great answer! I am using the Exponent and Modulus matching technique.

Comment: Btw your first sentence does not make that much sense. I should encrypt with public and decrypt with PRIVATE right?

Comment: @Evgeni Petrov: Yes, you are right. I have corrected the sentence.

Comment: Can't edit because it isn't enough characters, but `RSAKeyParameters` should be `RsaKeyParameters`

Answer (score 0):

> I am trying to encrypt some text (private key) and decrypt some text
>   (public key).

The public key is not intended to be used for decryption. In PKI, the public key is shared for multiple parties to encrypt data it intends to send to holders of the private key and the private key is then used to decrypt the data submitted.

Comment: Though signing is done by encrypting a secure hash of the content signed with a private key, which can then be verified by decrypting with the public. A nit-pick though, +1 all the same.

Comment: So how should I check if private and public key match?